# Jumping to a specific id section on a different page

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am creating a portfolio project using handlebars and nodeJS. On my home(index) page, I have two sections down the page called 'about me' and 'contact me'. My nav bar also contains two buttons labeled 'about me' and 'contact me'. Both my 'contact me' and 'about me' have id tags with corresponding names.
I understand that when on the home page already, I can simply use
`<ahref="#about-me-ID">About Me</a>`
and this will automatically scroll down the page for me.

However, my issue is when I am not on the home page, but say one of my project pages. They also have the same nav bar, so if I want to click on 'contact me', simply using
`<ahref="#about-me-ID">About Me</a>`
it will obviously not work because that page does not contain the section with that id.

So my question is, if I am on a project page and I click on the 'contact me'/'about me' button in the nav bar, how do I get back to the home page and then also have it scroll down to those sections?

From this link, https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-do-i-link-jump-to-a-specific-section-on-a-different-page/5646 I was hoping to get answers. But since I am using handlebars instead of html, this option does not work for me.Or at least I do not think it does.

I have my hbs all stored in a folder called views. The index.hbs is in /public/views. However my project pages are store in /public/views/partials <-- just for reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Handlebars doesn't change anything regarding your issue because your issue has to  do only with HTML, regardless of how it is produced. For your anchor's `href` value, you just need to put the path of the page before the id hash. For the links to your home page, this would be a slash (the path to your home page) plus a hash followed by the id of the element to which you want to be scrolled - `href="/#about-md-ID"`.

Comment: Great that worked! Thanks so much. Another  question if you don't mind? You're super helpful! <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874844/how-redirect-from-a-hbshandlebars-page-to-a-html-page>