# How redirect from a hbs(handlebars) page to a html page

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, hbs

I am working on my portfolio project. I am using handlebars and nodeJS.

I have a section called projects where I list 4 different projects to showcase. I have an index.js where all my routing is done. Projects 1,3,4 work just fine. These all will be clicked on from a project section on my index page.

However, I am so lost on how to route my project 2. Projects 1,3,4 are all handlebars(.hbs). But my project 2 is an html page. As seen in my code snippet, the html is store under the same /public folder as all my other code. However, I still get the error "Failed to lookup view "../public/views/fountainWebsite/html/home" in views directory". I am not sure how this needs to be done??

```
// === VARIABLES === //
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var handlebars = require("express-handlebars");
var path = require("path");
var router = express.Router();  //creates a router object

 //===== view ENGINE SET UP =====//
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.engine(
    "hbs",
    handlebars({
      layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, "/public/views/layouts"),
      partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, "/public/views/partials"), 
      extname: ".hbs", //expected file extension for handlebars files
      defaultLayout: "layout" //default layout for app, general template for all pages in app
    })
);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
 
//thought this would maybe fix the error?? It didn't//
// app.set("fountainWebsite", path.join(__dirname, "fountainWebsite")); //

app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));


//===== .GET PAGES =====//

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => { 
    res.render('../public/views/index', {title: 'Home Page', css:['../public/css/style.css'], js:['../public/js/navBar.js']});
});
app.use('/', router);

router.get('/project1', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('../public/views/partials/project1', {title: 'Data Structures', css:['../public/css/projects.css'], js:['../public/js/navBar.js']});
});

//error here//
router.get('/project2', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('../public/views/fountainWebsite/html/home');
});

router.get('/project3', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('../public/views/partials/project3', {title: 'This Portfolio', css:['../public/css/projects.css'], js:['../public/js/navBar.js']});
});

router.get('/project4', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('../public/views/partials/project4', {title: 'Dictionary', css:['../public/css/projects.css'], js:['../public/js/navBar.js']});
});
```

Comment: I would just make project 2 a Handlebars view as well. It will be much easier to make everything consistent. And, as any HTML should be valid in a Handlebars template, you may just need to change the extension of the file from .html to .hbs. As an additional comment, I don't think your views should be in a public folder - they are rendered server-side and are not files your users would download directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important that we understand what our code is doing. Let's start with the route handler for `/project2`:

```
router.get('/project2', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('../public/views/fountainWebsite/html/home');
});
```

This is telling Express to listen for a request with the path `/project2` and to render the file at `../public/views/fountainWebsite/html/home`.

Handlebars requires an extension (like `.hbs`) in order to know which view engines to use to render the file. As we have omitted an extension from our file path, Express will assume the extension is `.hbs` because that's what we told it to do when we called `app.set("view engine", "hbs");`

I have to assume that your file path with extension is `../public/views/fountainWebsite/html/home.html` since you have put it in a folder called "html". If this is the case, Handlebars is not going to find this file because it is looking for `../public/views/fountainWebsite/html/home.hbs` and it will throw an Error.

The simple solution would be to rename this file with a `.hbs` extension. This will at least allow Express to locate the file and render it through the Handlebars view engine.

However, one problem with this approach may be that this view gets rendered wrapped in your layout.hbs file and you do not want that. Perhaps you want this HTML file to be unprocessed and served as a static asset.

In this case, you could remove the `/project2` route handler and let Express serve this file as a static asset. Since you have already registered your `public/` folder as static assets folder with the call `app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));` and your file path shows that this HTML file is already within the `public/` folder, you should be able to request this HTML directly from your browser at the path `/public/views/fountainWebsite/html/home.html`.

Comment: Ya I was hoping to keep it as an html because it isn't just one file, it 6 html's and 6 css' to go with that. It is from a 'mock' website I made. So I was hoping to avoid changing the home page from home.html to home.hbs because then I need to change everything over.

Comment: So I tried putting the path "/public/views/fountainWebsite/html/home.html" with the ```<a href>``` link directly but it didn't work.    I also tried putting it as the path for the '/project2' in the index.js file but I see now with your explanation that the app is looking for an hbs file so I cannot do it there.

Comment: I also have css and images go with all my html's for my mock website. So I had those all in the /public/views/fountainWebsite folder. With that set up, the fountain website worked when I opened it individual. But I am not sure if it's good practice to have a whole website folder within the views folder.

Comment: @TasiTele: I think it would make most sense to have the `fountainWebsite` folder be a subfolder within the `public` folder. Furthermore, I don't think the `views` folder should be in the `public` folder because the views are not files that your users download directly.

Comment: So I originally had the fountainWebsite as a subfolder under public. And css and html were subfolders under that.  So /public/fountainWebsite/html/home.html.  But the issue I was having with that was again, I didn't know how to route it. The hbs files(under public/views/layout) were not able to find the home page.

Comment: When in my /public/views/index   I try linking my html page directly like: ```<a  href="./public/fountainWebsite/html/home">``` and the error message I gett is "Cannot GET /public/fountainWebsite/html/home"

Comment: @TasiTele: You would need to include the ".html" extension.

Comment: Okay great! Last question. Once I get into my fountain html pages. How do I get back out? I included a "Back to Portfolio" <a href> tag but none of my routes are working.  I cannot use index.hbs? I have tried: ```/public/views/layout.hbs``` and also ```/public/index(js)/```.  Not sure how make the correct route since my index page is an hbs gotten through the index.js?

Comment: @TasiTele: You can't link to .hbs files, they are rendered on the server. Just link to the site root - ie., `/`.

Comment: Gotcha I understand how it all flows now! I cant thank you enough!! You save my portfolio!